# Method to read DBF files efficiently python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dbf

**I have the following method to open DBF files, but it performs very slow, I´m looking to open large DBF files, I need to efficient my method. Need Help. Thanxs **

```
def lectura_tablas(nombre_tabla):
    table_name=nombre_tabla
    table_ventas = DBF(f'{table_name}', load=True,ignore_missing_memofile=True)
    table_new=[]
    for x in range(0,len(table_ventas.records)):
        table_new.append(OrderedDict(table_ventas.records[x]))
    dataframe= pd.DataFrame(table_new)
    return dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code ought to work. A slowness might be caused by a "Schlemiel the Painter" problem in the loop (the fact that you use load=True makes this unlikely, but it's the only possibility I see). Try rewriting it like this:

for record in table_ventas:
        table_new.append(record)

This *ought* to use the standard iterator on the DBF object, which *ought* to already return an `OrderedDict`.

Other than that, you might try recompiling the DBF into some other format which is more efficiently accessed and see whether the overall time improves any.